# Scriptaculous effect.slideup jerky in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, animation, scriptaculous

I have a simple Effect.SlideUp("div_name") using scriptaculous in a rails app.
I placed a div within this div as mentioned by this guy (http://goingspare.wordpress.com/2007/08/03/fix-jerky-scriptaculous-scriptaculous-animation-effects/) and everything works great ... in Chrome.

However, in Firefox the div is jerky and looks ugly-assed.  Any suggestions on how to solve this? Should I be looking to JQuery?

Here is the code:

```
     New thread | New comment New comment  


    <div id="create_thread" style="display:none">

        <div id="new_thread_or_comment_inner">

            New thread <br />

            <% remote_form_for :commentthread, :url => { :action => 'createthread' } do |f| %>
                <textarea name="commentthread[text]" id="commentthread_text" >
                </textarea>

                <a href="javascript:cancelThread()" class="button">Cancel</a>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
            <% end %>

        </div>

    </div>
```

The create_thread div scrolls down with Effect.SlideDown('create_thread', { duration: 0.3 }); but the "New thread | New comment New comment " line bounces all over the place, maybe I need some buffer?  I have emptied the div but still no luck.

Cheers,

Slothistype

Comment: Don't know why it's not looking great but for the jerkiness, have you tried disabling firebug?

Comment: Yep but there is no change, still the text above the div jumps about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by decreasing the framerate to 15

, fps:15 }

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with slides with Jquery in Firefox and all browsers.  It works very well.  http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/.  Unless you need certain things in scriptaculous, id give Jquery a go.

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/116173  seems like someone else had a problem like this too, are you loading a lot of things in that div?  I have not had any problems with large slide animations either in jquery.

Comment: the problem is I am using rails 2.3 so would like to use coupled javascript instead of JQuery.